# TextView in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which the layout is independent of screen resolution.
Now my problem is that in TextView the textview layout does change itself when the resolution of screen changes but the size of text remain same.

I want that when the resolution is high, according to that the text size should also adjust itself(i.e. text size should be changed).
And simillarly when resolution is low the text size sholud also shrink.

But here when i reduce Y-AXIS to an extent the text vanishes.

I will really appriciate any answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `sp` for your `android:textSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a values folder for each of the four densities and make a common dimension value for each density.

So at low density it is a certain value, medium density it is a certain value and so on.